# How do I browse diff of a file in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am currently using [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) as my source control in Windows. How do I view the diff of a single file as I move through the different revisions quickly? Or is there a better tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see the revisions of the file you can right click the file and choose

> TortoiseSVN -> Show Log

Then, from there you can select multiple items and choose Compare Revisions

Answer (score 3):

I think what you might really like is an open source tool called [svn-time-lapse-view](http://code.google.com/p/svn-time-lapse-view/).

It's a Java executable jar file that lets you load all the revisions for a file and then use a slider to scroll/cycle through all of the version changes with the diff shown below the slider.

Much faster than opening the log and selecting two files over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to have a look at the Blame tool.  It will annotate each line of source with the revision number in which it was last modified.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the file > TurtoiseSVN > Diff or Diff with previous version. You can also use Show Log, then right-click the file and use any of the "Compare" options.
I personally use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) for merging and showing differences.